# application-defined or object-defined on variable rows and multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I don't think this is a duplicate, however I apologize if it is.

I am very new to VBA, so I was hoping to have someone look over my code and help me troubleshoot the application-defined or object-defined error I am getting on the line below:

```
Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P10:" & Cells(i, 0).Address) 'Trying to select rows based on value in i starting with P10
```

Here is the full macro:

```
Sub freeze2()

Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim aCell   As Range
Dim strg()  As String
Dim count   As Integer
Dim i       As Integer
Dim size As Integer

size = ActiveSheet.Range("B9:B79").Find(What:=Worksheets("Email Template").Range("B5").Value) 'Looks for current fiscal week

Debug.Print size
count = 0

For i = 1 To size 'should represent current fiscal week back to first week of year, so for this week the range would be 1 to 40
Next i
ReDim numbers(size)

' Get each RED sheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Tab.Color = 255 Then                      ' Find only RED tabs
    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Debug.Print "Name of Red Sheet: '" & ws.Name & "'"        ' Debug...

    Sheets(ws.Name).Select
    Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P10:" & Cells(i, 0).Address) 'Trying to         select rows based on value in i starting with P10
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set aCell = Range("H10") 'Taking acell and hopefully copying as values to H10
        'Selection.copy
        'Range("H10").Select
        'Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else

    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False         ' Unselect cell
End If
```

Next ws

End Sub

All I am trying to do is select a range of cells (always one column however row size will change each week) and copy those values into another column. This range is in the same place on all red sheets.

Comment: Your reference isn't valid. Cell indexing starts at 1, not 0.

Comment: there is no 0 column.  Column A is 1 and so on.  Change the `ActiveSheet.Range("P10:" & Cells(i, 0).Address)` to `ActiveSheet.Range("P10", ActiveSheet.Cells(i,16))`

Comment: wow, the more I read the less I understand.  Your for loop does nothing.  the i you reference in the broken line will always be `size +1`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I feel silly. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Scott Craner was this really necessary?  wow, the more I read the less I understand.  Not super helpful.

Comment: To be precise @RyanWildry it is possible to do relative indexing with `Range.Cells`, you can use `0` or even *negative* values, provided that the result (basically the same as `Offset` method) is a valid range :)

Comment: @DavidZemens agreed, but as offset wasn't mentioned I felt it best to keep the answer simple as it would resolve the issue posted.

Comment: @RyanWildry `Offset` isn't required. Any `Range.Cells` can be zero- or negative indexed, provided that the equivalent offset is a valid range. For example, `Range("B3").Cells(-1).Address` yields "B1"

Comment: The concept, not the function.

Comment: Right, and I'm not disputing that OP had an invalid reference, what I'm disputing is that "Cell indexing starts at 1, not 0".  This is true for `Worksheet.Cells` but it is not always (actually, rarely) true for `Range.Cells`  Basically I am just trying to confuse everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this to show Ryan's edit

Set aCell = ActiveSheet.Range("P10:" & Cells(i, 1).Address) 'Trying to select rows based on value in i starting with P10

Comment: You should watch this video series on YouTube: [Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I will take a look at those!